# Bash and file command sample size

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script to process some files automatically and one subjob is to use `iconv` to re-encode source files if they are not of my liking. For that I use:

```
enc=$(file -b --mime-encoding "$file")                   # get the encoding

if [ "$enc" = "iso-8859-1" ] || [ "$enc" = "us-ascii" ]  # no need to encode these
then                                                     
    unset enc
fi

cat "$file" |                                            # conditional encoding below
    ( [[ "${enc}" ]] && iconv -f "$enc" -t iso-8859-1 || cat ) |
    awk '{# code to process file further}' > "$newfile"
```

The problem is that I have a file which is UTF8 but `file` falsely recognizes it as ASCII. The first non-ASCII character is character #314206 which is on line #1028. Apparently there is some sample size for `file`, for example if I convert the file from fixed width to character delimited the first non-ASCII character is char #80872 and `file` recognizes the file encoding correctly. So I guess there is a sample size which is between those 2 values.

(**TL;DR**) 
Is there a way to instruct `file` to take a larger sample or read the whole source file, or some other bash friendly way of finding out the encoding?

I played around with `file -P` but couldn't affect the outcome with that. `man file` didn't help me any further and googling *file command sample size* was not very promising.

(if you wonder about the conditional approach there are some other tasks to process also not shown in the code sample)

Comment: There's no way of finding out the encoding. You can only guess, and when guessing, mistakes are possible.

Comment: Sure, but in this case by changing the sample size I would get the correct answer. If there is no way of changing the sample size, I guess I need to test for the default sample size and loop and test the file with `file` in parts.

Comment: Maybe try with `chardet`?

Comment: Man, that `chardet` is s l o w. 1.7 MB in 1:09. But it returned the encoding correctly.

Comment: Why are you unsetting `enc` inside a conditional, only to make *another* conditional check on the result of `$enc`?

Comment: @chepner Quick and dirty, script still under construction.

Comment: Have you tried `file -k`?

Comment: @randomir Yes. With the same outcome: `ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators` vs. `ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators\012- data`.

Comment: Seems like `file -P bytes=10000000` works for me (`bytes`, i.e. max number of bytes to read from file defaults to 1048576). You can set `bytes` to your largest file size.

Comment: Hmm, my `file` does not support that (`file: Unknown param bytes=1000000`, I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, with `file-5.25`) but that would definitely be the solution.

Comment: @randomir Which version of `file`are you using? (`file -v`)?

Comment: The `bytes` param is available since at least v5.28. Zesty packs 5.29. (The latest version is 5.32.)

Comment: @randomir Turn that to an anwser, please, for future generations to feast on.

Comment: Will do in a minute, glad we solved this.

Comment: BTW, consider using `{ ...; }` instead of `( ... )` for grouping -- the parens create an explicit subshell, which has a performance cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `file` will only analyze the first `1048576` bytes of the file.

An option to control this limit was added in commit [`d04de269`](https://github.com/file/file/commit/d04de269e0b06ccd0a7d1bf4974fed1d75be7d9e), and it's available in `file` since [version 5.26](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/ChangeLog#L123) (2016-04-16). It is controlled with the `-P` option, parameter named `bytes`:

> ```
> -P, --parameter name=value
>     Set various parameter limits.
>         Name         Default    Explanation
>         ...
>         bytes        1048576    max number of bytes to read from file
> ```

So, you can just set the `bytes` limit to the size of your largest file, e.g. 100 MB:

```
$ file -P bytes=104857600 file
```